# How to set scroll to last cell ccTableView cocos2d html5

Tags: html, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

How to set scroll to last cell of cc.TableView as tbl.scrollTo(x,y) or tbl.scrollToBottom() ?

Answer (score 1):

```
tableView.setContentOffset(cc.p(0,0));
```

The content offset of a CCTableView is a point cc.p(x,y), where x stands for horizontal offset and y for vertical.

In a vertically filled CCTableView, its y content offset ranges from

```
   tableView.getViewSize().height-tableView.getContentSize().height // tableView at top
```

to

```
   0 // tableView at bottom
```

and x content offset equals 0.